# Accord Framework HiddenMarkovClassifier(TDistribution, TObservation) API

Tags: accord.net

When I upgrade to Accord Framework 3.2.0 and run software I get 2 'obsolete' errors:

Warning 1   'HiddenMarkovClassifier'<'MultivariateNormalDistribution'>'' is obsolete: 'Please use HiddenMarkovClassifier'<'TDistribution, TObservation'>' instead.'

Warning 14  'BaumWelchLearning'<'MultivariateNormalDistribution'>' is obsolete: 'Please use BaumWelchLearning'<'TDistribution, TObservation'>' instead.'

There is no apparent API for the BaumWelchLearning'<'TDistribution, TObservation'>'.  When I go to the new API for HiddenMarkovClassifier'<'TDistribution'>' and the relatively minor changes reflected on that documentation it does not fix the 2 issues above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The new API expects the type of the observations you are using (i.e. double or double[]) to be passed as the second generic argument of the learning algorithm. Please see the examples at http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Markov_Learning_HiddenMarkovClassifierLearning_2.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The was answered in updated documentation for Accord Framework in Google Groups Support :  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/accord-net/CdB4vsUNr_Y